# MySQL %e2%80%93 тире в базе данных

Tags: база-данных, php, mysql

Всем привет! Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Из базы данных беру строку, она содержит английский текст и вот такое %e2%80%93. Это тире, похоже оно в UTF-8 (hex.) но точно не знаю. Мне надо чтобы оно выводилось (вместе с остальным текстом) через echo ввиде тире, т.е. надо это как-то перекодировать? Заменить тупо на тире "-" не годится, т.к. могут быть другие подобные символы в других строках. В инете посмотрел, что-то не понятно ничего.

Comment: Думаю стоит разобраться почему такие данные попали в базу.

Answer (score 1):

Такой вариант:

```
echo urldecode('Hello %e2%80%93 World'); // Hello – World
```